# Stripe's Rail's Checkout Guide code clarification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm currently looking at the following [guide](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/rails) from Stripe, and came across this chunk of code.

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => ENV['stripe_test_publishable_key'],
  :secret_key      => ENV['stripe_test_secret_key']
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

I think I understand what the first half is saying, but what exactly is `Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]` doing? After doing a quick CTRL+F, `Stripe.api_key` isn't used anywhere.

Upon finishing the guide, I commented out that line and the app still works fine when checking out.

Can someone explain why that line was included in the first place, and is it even needed?

Comment: `Publishable API` keys are meant solely to identify your account with Stripe, they aren't secret. In other words, they can safely be published in places like your Stripe.js JavaScript code, or in an Android or iPhone app. Publishable keys only have the power to create tokens.

`Secret API` keys should never be published, and must be kept confidentially on your own servers. These keys can perform any API request to Stripe without restriction. Reference: https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/dashboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When making calls to Stripe's API, you need to provide your secret key so Stripe can identify you.

So `Stripe.api_key` is used internally by the [Stripe Ruby gem](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby) to make API calls on your behalf.

It's surprising that your app works when you comment this line, because if you don't specify a key, all API calls should fail with the following exception:

> `Stripe::AuthenticationError`: No API key provided. Set your API key using "Stripe.api_key = ". You can generate API keys from the Stripe web interface. See https://stripe.com/api for details, or email support@stripe.com if you have any questions.

Note that [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) will display the green checkmark when it successfully turns card details into a token. That doesn't mean the charge has been created yet! That may be why you think commenting out `Stripe.api_key` has no effect, but if you check your [logs](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/overview) in your dashboard, you should see that the token creation request isn't followed by a charge creation request (because without your API key, Stripe has no way of telling it's you who made the request!).